# Recurrence equation solution help

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have come across a recurrence relation i.e

$$f(a,b) = f(a-1,b) + f(a-1,b-1)$$
and the base case is $f(x,0) = 2$ for any positive $x$ and
$f(x,y) = 0$ if $x \leq y$. Note that $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Can anyone please tell me if we can derive a formula for this equation using some relation between $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plase take a look at the [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).
If you try and calculate some values, you should see that your recurrence is very simmilar up to a factor 2, at least for $b\geq 0$. So the result ist $f(a,b) = 2 {a \choose b}$.

Comment: shouldn't that be 2*(aCb)?

Comment: I think you are right. Sorry for my sloppines.

Comment: My bad it is 2*(a-1Cb) if(a>2)
and 2 if a<=2